# What is Vampirism - how does it work?

Tags: rogue-legacy

The 'Blood' items from the Blacksmith, such as 'Blood Cape' all give +1 to Vampirism.

What does Vampirism do?

Comment: @fbueckert That question is about runes, this one is aimed at equipment.

Comment: @3ventic The example is about equipment, but I believe the question is asking how that skill works generally.  Which still may or may not be a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, this pretty much answers my question - for whatever reason, i could only get 1 question to come up for the tag [rogue-legacy] in a search.

Try for yourself: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-legacy

Comment: Although the equipment and runes are functionally the same, I believe they are named somewhat differently(vampire rune vs vampirism on equipment) and therefore not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vampirism on equipment works the same way as the vampire rune. After each kill you get 2 hp back. These effects stack with other weapons and runes.

[See this answer for more information about vampire, siphon, & balance runes.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/122175/30210)